# Java | KeyListener | Basic

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, keylistener

How can I change or hide that JTextField from showing to the user and still get the users typed keys? I tried using "KeyCodeT.setVisible(false);", but it didn't work.

This is what I'm talking about: http://oi46.tinypic.com/35hobbn.jpg

Full code here: http://pastebin.com/8t3cTLKX

```
JTextField KeyCodeT = new JTextField("Key Code:");

public KeyProgram() {
    KeyCodeT.addKeyListener(this);
    KeyCodeT.setEditable(false);
    add(KeyCodeT);
    setSize(300, 300);      
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Key Pressed!!!");

    if (e.getKeyCode() == 27) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good  Bye");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Key Released!!!");
    KeyCodeT.setText("Key Code:" + e.getKeyCode());

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   KeyProgram key = new KeyProgram();
   key.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You can change to background of the textbox to that of the panel behind and remove the border of the textbox

Comment: 1) *"Full code here"* For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) For Swing, look into [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: The `JTextfield` only recieves input when it has focus. How is this recognized by your users? Perhaps it is good to consider whether this is the right approach for your requirements.

Comment: unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == 27)
```

Don't use magic numbers. People reading your code don't know what that is. Instead use:

```
KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE
```

However, you should not even be using a KeyListener for this. Instead you should be using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below:

```
JTextField textField= new JTextField();
textField.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Panel.background")); // set the text box background color to color of component behind
textField.setBorder(null); // remove the text box border
```

This looks like below:

[image: Transparent/Invisible text box sample]

NOTE: *This may not be the best approach for this requirement, but this does work.*

Comment: @user2287319 It's common courtesy to "upvote" and/or "accept" an answer here on SO. Feel free to check the answer you feel that solves your problem.